# How to register generic type handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

I'm trying to make my queries and handlers generic but I'm getting exceptions

> InvalidOperationException: Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[AL.Services.CQRS.Queries.Access.GetAccessesQuery`1[AL.Core.Entities.Telephone],AL.Services.CQRS.QueryResponses.Access.ObjectAccessesResponse]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.
>
> ArgumentException: The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition. (Parameter 'instantiation')

My classes

```
public class GetAccessesQuery<TEntity> : IRequest<ObjectAccessesResponse> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public GetAccessesQuery(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}


public class GetAccessesHandler<TEntity> : IRequestHandler<GetAccessesQuery<TEntity>, ObjectAccessesResponse> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    public GetAccessesHandler()
    {
        
    }
    public async Task<ObjectAccessesResponse> Handle(GetAccessesQuery<TEntity> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

In controller

```
var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetAccessesQuery<Telephone>(telephoneId));
```

But I can't figure how should I register them in startup.cs
Current startup.cs

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>).Assembly);
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(UserIdBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(GetAccessesHandler<>));
services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>).Assembly);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? In the middleware or in controller? Please have a look [here in offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6, try this in case you are using multiple project solution

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```